# How to set a variable in a shortcode and reference it in another shortcode in the same post?

Tags: shortcode

How can I define two shortcodes in functions.php to be able to set a variable using a shortcode in a post, and use it in another shortcode in the same post.

For example, in the beggining of the post:

```
[SET_VARIABLE VALUE=HELLO]
```

Then, later in that same post

```
[PRINT_VARIABLE]
```

returns HELLO

Comment: so what problems did you run into while implementing this? what is the actuall difficulty you faced and you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

In functions.php, where do you place your shortcode functions, you have to declare a global variable, then set its value in first shortcode function and use its value in second function.